# dynamic Button class does not update after the array change

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

So I have an array of objects. I iterate through this array and create a button for each object.
When a button is pressed that object of the button pressed has a value "active" that will be set to true. when another button is pressed its "active" value is now true all all the other ones are turned to false.

it looks like this

```
myarray.map(item =>
        <Button
          className={item.active? "btn-active" : "btn-disabled"}
          onClick={() => setActive(item);
          }}
        >
          {item.active? "Checking..." : "Start"}
        </Button>
)
```

The behavior I expect is when a button is pressed it turns to action, and all the rest remain inactive, when a new button is pressed the new button is now active and all the rest are disabled. only one active button at a time.

However, the issue I am having is when a new button is pressed it turns to active, but the old one does not change class and stays active also even though it "active" property is set to false.

Any idea how can I fix this behavior?

Comment: `setActive{item}` is not the correct way to invoke a function, it should be `setActive(item)`.

Comment: Where are you resetting the `active` state for other buttons? Looks like you're directly calling the state updater on click,

Comment: I think you can save index of active item as state variable, then can compare with current iterator.

Comment: sorry, I made a typo when writing the code here. I did copy past. in the actual code, it is correct.

Comment: what does `setActive` do and how is state stored for `myarray` ?

I suggest adding these to your code snippet. Perhaps a stripped down but operational example of your problem would help.

Comment: the array is stored in state and it change the object's value to active: true all the other one change it to false

Comment: the issue seems to be it does not rerender those buttons again

Comment: any chance we could see `setActive`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a full picture of how you are using state, here is a working example. Another issue I seen is that you are missing a key on your mapped jsx element.

It's possible you are not mutating myarray statefully.

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [myarray, setMyarray] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, active: false },
    { id: 2, active: false }
  ]);

  const setActive = (id) => {
    setMyarray((prev) =>
      prev.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return { ...item, active: true };
        }
        return { ...item, active: false };
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {myarray.map((item) => (
        <button
          key={`button-${item.id}`}
          className={item.active ? "btn-active" : "btn-disabled"}
          onClick={() => setActive(item.id)}
        >
          {item.active ? "Checking..." : "Start"}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-shirley-i24v0z

Comment: You forgot to update the other buttons with `active: false`

Comment: Try it now. That's code that you'd be better sharing if its the source of your error. I'm only adding place holders.